# Storage Migration Using System Center Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: migration, system-center, scvmm

I have 2 sites with 2 Hyper-V clusters.
I'm running System Center VMM in Dublin which monitors my servers in the USA.
If I want to do a storage migration from one `LUN` to another on my USA cluster, will the script run from the Hyper-v Servers or from the VMM server in Dublin?

Will there be a latency problem or will it run in the local server?

I'm preparing to do a test myself but if someone has the answer I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The script could be run from any of the servers as long as it can find the locations to which it is pointing to. I would prefer to run it from the `VMM` host, since that's your monitoring machine.

As for latency, there should be no difference (unless you have network issues) because you mentioned the migration is performed between 2 `LUNs` located within the same site.

### EDIT

As long as you're not migrating to or from your `VMM` host, the operation is only controller by the server but not executed by or through it.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply. Because the VMM server is managing the cluster on the other side of the atlantic. If I create a storage migration from the VMM server. do you think it will buffer the copy to the VMM server before copying to the new LUN or copy direct? I hope this makes more sense

Comment: @Jaoibh, I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had guessed that was the way it should work logically. But had to be sure. Thanks for the reply